# Update multi table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, multi-table

I'm trying to update mysql multiple tables, although there's no error but the changes are not reflected in the mysql database. Please let me if i would need to use JOIN to put the query update within one string.

Do I also still need

```
mysqli_query($conn, $sqlCD) or die(mysqli_error($conn)); in the below ? 

  $pCDTitle = filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'CDTitle') ? $_GET['CDTitle']: null;         // store all parameter in variable
  $pCDPubName = filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'CDPub') ? $_GET['CDPub']: null;
  $pCDYear = filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'CDYear') ? $_GET['CDYear']: null;
  $pCDCategory = filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'CDCat') ? $_GET['CDCat']: null;        
  $pCDPrice = filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'CDPrice') ? $_GET['CDPrice']: null;
  $pCDID = filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'CDID') ? $_GET['CDID']: null;
  $pCDPubID = filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'pubID') ? $_GET['pubID']: null;    

$sqlCD = mysql_query("UPDATE nmc_cd SET CDTitle='$pCDTitle', CDYear='$pCDYear', CDPrice='$pCDPrice'");
$sqlCD2 = mysql_query("UPDATE nmc_category SET catDesc='$pCDCategory'");
$sqlCD3 = mysql_query("UPDATE nmc_publisher SET pubName='$pCDPubName'");

//mysqli_query($conn, $sqlCD) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
//mysqli_query($conn, $sqlCD2) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
//mysqli_query($conn, $sqlCD3) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: mixing mysql and mysqli !!

Answer (score 3):

You have to change the query:

```
$sqlCD = mysql_query("UPDATE nmc_cd SET CDTitle=$pCDTitle, CDYear=$pCDYear, CDPrice=$pCDPrice");
$sqlCD2 = mysql_query("UPDATE nmc_category SET catDesc=$pCDCategory");
$sqlCD3 = mysql_query("UPDATE nmc_publisher SET pubName=$pCDPubName");
```

Reason:
If a string in Double qoutes "" have a php variable like $test the its value is automatically in the string but if you use single qoute '' then its the variable name prints.
For example:

```
$test = 5;
echo "The number is $test"; //The number is 5 prints
echo 'The number is $test'; //The number is $test prints
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
mysqli_query($conn, $sqlCD) or die(mysqli_error($conn)); in the below ? 

  $pCDTitle = filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'CDTitle') ? $_GET['CDTitle']: null;         // store all parameter in variable
  $pCDPubName = filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'CDPub') ? $_GET['CDPub']: null;
  $pCDYear = filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'CDYear') ? $_GET['CDYear']: null;
  $pCDCategory = filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'CDCat') ? $_GET['CDCat']: null;        
  $pCDPrice = filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'CDPrice') ? $_GET['CDPrice']: null;
  $pCDID = filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'CDID') ? $_GET['CDID']: null;
  $pCDPubID = filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'pubID') ? $_GET['pubID']: null;    

$sqlCD = mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE nmc_cd SET CDTitle='$pCDTitle', CDYear='$pCDYear', CDPrice='$pCDPrice'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$sqlCD2 = mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE nmc_category SET catDesc='$pCDCategory'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$sqlCD3 = mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE nmc_publisher SET pubName='$pCDPubName'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
mysqli_close($conn);
```

try this.

Comment: Thanks but realize it replace the entire database.. i think it's lacking the row ID and directing it to only update the selected row...